# Convert rows of Div values into an array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, associative-array

Example:
I have a variable amount of rows, each with 3 divs with classes like so:

```
<div class="row> 
<div class='date'>1/2/2018</div> 
<div class='event'>concert</div>
<div class='act'>Pink Floyd</div>
</div>

<div class="row> 
<div class='date'>12/5/2017</div> 
<div class='event'>dj set</div>
<div class='act'>Moby</div>
</div>

<div class="row> 
<div class='date'>5/5/2018</div> 
<div class='event'>movie</div>
<div class='act'>Ant-Man</div>
</div>
```

How can I use jQuery to gather them into an associative array that I'll be passing to php to INSERT into a database table?

Comment: Array.from($('div'))

Comment: Can you tell me more about how that works. Wouldn't it collect the divs with the div class too?

Comment: you said `How can I use jQuery to gather them into an array` - that's how ... if you need particular format of the output, please include that in your question, along with any actual attempts you may have made to solve your own problem

Comment: I tried it out here https://jsfiddle.net/c1bpy07d/, that kind of works. Is there a way to have it be an associative array?

Comment: Is there a simple way to get them outputted as comma delimited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to loop thru the `.row` div. Use `reduce` to group the inner divs into a js object.

```js
var result = $('.row').map(function() {
  return $(this).find('div').toArray().reduce(function(c, v) {
    c[$(v).attr('class')] = $(v).text();
    return c;
  }, {});
}).get();


console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class='date'>1/2/2018</div>
  <div class='event'>concert</div>
  <div class='act'>Pink Floyd</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class='date'>12/5/2017</div>
  <div class='event'>dj set</div>
  <div class='act'>Moby</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class='date'>5/5/2018</div>
  <div class='event'>movie</div>
  <div class='act'>Ant-Man</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To select each all the div with the class row use this

```
  var rows=$('div.row');
```

To loop through it use this

```
var array=[];
for(var i=0;i <rows.length;i++){
$.each(rows,function(){
var children=this.children('div');
$.each(children,function(){
var index=this.attr('class');
var value=this.text();
array[i][index]=value;
});
});
}
```

console.log(array);

Comment: That nicely gets the following: https://jsfiddle.net/sqL2gfny/ though I'm not clear on how to loop through just a list in php with that. Is there a way to make an associative array from it?

Comment: I set that up here https://jsfiddle.net/Ldn7e964/ , but I'm not sure what code I should put in the brakets and how